# iPhone UI Design: Okay button or no okay button

Tags: iphone, button, notifications

I am compulsive and like visually clean designs.

Theres a pop up in my app that tells the user that there's an error.

I made a clear button over the entire pop up (about 200x100 px) so the user can just touch the notification to dismiss it.

But i'm afraid the user might not know that you can just touch the pop up to dissmiss and would go crazy looking for the "OKAY" button.

Do you guys think the OKAY button is necessary or is a giant clear button overlaying the notification good enough?

note: the whole notification actually looks like a button because of rounded corners and some button like borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever users can misinterpret, they will (just look at some of the low ranked App store reviews for examples).

So, unless it clutters your UI and/or makes things even more confusing, a clear indication of how get rid of or move beyond your popup will certainly reduce the chances for any user confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of your design, but I would go for an OK button. There might be people in the world who don't understand it and blame your app.

Or you leave out the button and make the notification disappear by itself after, say 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go the Microsoft way:
- add the "Okay" button
- add a smaller checkbox with the caption "don't ask me again"
- when the okay button is clicked and the checkbox is marked, open an additional dialog notifying the user that the Okay button will no longer be displayed, but that they can clear that setting in the preferences menu
- create the preferences menu as described

Now who says Microsoft suck at UI ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the OK button. Not only will it be more familiar for users, but you won't have any problem with Apple's approval process. Depending on the reviewer they might reject the app for not conforming to the Human Interface Guidelines.